# facebook send notification to users

Tags: php, facebook

i want to send notification who access my app.i use following code.
but it not work.i was goggling about it.but every example looks like my one.but it not work for me.
here is my code

```
 require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'myappid',
  'secret' => 'myappsecret',
)); 
$app_id='myappid';
$app_secret='myappsecret';
$app_access_token=$app_id.'|'.$app_secret;
$user_id='359211054272153';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
  ));
$response = $facebook->api( '/359211054272153/notifications', 'POST/v2.2/', array(

                'template' => 'You have received a new message.',

                'href' => 'RELATIVE URL',

                'access_token' => $app_access_token
            ) );
```

Comment: Is your app a canvas app?

Comment: What’s the response you get for your API call?

Comment: unsupported post request.

Comment: `POST/v2.2/` is wrong – the method is just `POST`, the API version needs to be specified as a prefix to the path, `/v2.2/user-id/…`

Comment: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported method

Comment: You’re using the old v3 version of the PHP SDK there? Try leaving out the API version then. Or try using the current v4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am used old version of Facebook sdk  it want to real user id.
but currently
Facebook gives app scoped userid. thats the error.

using new sdk v4 it not problem.